# Use python parse string of file path to json

Tags: python

I have the list of path string like below. How to convert it into complete json object?

```
foldersList = [
    '1/',
    '1/2/',
    '1/2/2.txt',
    '1/2/5/',
    '1/5.txt',
    '2/',
    '2/test.txt',
    'test.json'
]
```

How to convert it into complete json object like below

```
{
    "fileMenu":{
        "list":[
            {
                "fileType":"d",
                "name":"1",
                "subFolders":[
                    {
                        "fileType":"-",
                        "name":"5.txt",
                    },
                    {
                        "fileType":"d",
                        "name":"2",
                        "subFolders":[
                            {
                                "fileType":"-",
                                "name":"2.txt",
                            },
                            {
                                "date":1594983597000,
                                "fileType":"d",
                                "name":"5",
                                "size":0,
                                "subFolders":[]
                            }]
                    }]
            },
            {
                "fileType":"d",
                "name":"2",
                "subFolders":[{
                    "fileType":"-",
                    "name":"test.txt"
                }]
            },
            {
                "fileType":"-",
                "name":"test.json"
            }],
        "status":"OK"
    }
}
```

How to do this? I tried it with the some code snippets.

```
foldersList = [
    '1/',
    '1/2/',
    '1/2/2.txt',
    '1/2/5/',
    '1/5.txt',
    '2/',
    '2/test.txt',
    'test.json'
]

foldersJson = {}
nodeInfoList = []
nodeInfoDic = {}

for i, path in enumerate(foldersList):
    nodeInfoDic = foldersJson
    for j,node in enumerate(path.split('/')):
        if node != '':
            if nodeInfoDic.has_key(node) != True:
                nodeInfoDic[node] = {}
            nodeInfoDic = nodeInfoDic[node]
            # print(foldersJson)
    nodeInfoList.append(nodeInfoDic)
    print(nodeInfoList)

# print(foldersJson)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get a feeling on how to contribute. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Python.

Comment: Ok，i pasted my code